# Prevent Non Admin User from Installing Programs

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, user

How do you prevent non-admin users from installing a game on a computer? A game like [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/) would require the password because it installs it on all users, but a game like [Roblox](http://www.roblox.com) would not need a password because it installs it only on a specific user. How would I block games like [Roblox](http://www.roblox.com) from installing?

Note: I have an admin account.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. I just wasn't sure.

Comment: Probably create a startup script deleting the %AppData% folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via local group policy:

> Block users from installing or running programs in Windows 10/8/7

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-prevent-users-from-installing-programs-in-windows-7

> Type gpedit.msc in start search and hit Enter to open the Group Policy
>   Editor. Navigate to Computer Configurations > Administrative Templates
>
> > Windows Components > Windows Installer. In RHS pane double-click on Disable Windows Installer. Configure the option as required.
>
> This setting can prevent users from installing software on their systems or permit users to install only those programs offered by a
>   system administrator. If you enable this setting, you can use the
>   options in the Disable Windows Installer box to establish an
>   installation setting.
>
> The “Never” option indicates Windows Installer is fully enabled. Users
>   can install and upgrade software. This is the default behavior for
>   Windows Installer on Windows 2000 Professional, Windows XP
>   Professional, and Windows Vista when the policy is not configured.
>
> The “For non-managed apps only” option permits users to install only
>   those programs that a system administrator assigns (offers on the
>   desktop) or publishes (adds them to Add or Remove Programs). This is
>   the default behavior of Windows Installer on Windows Server 2003
>   family when the policy is not configured.
>
> The “Always” option indicates that Windows Installer is disabled.

Edit:  this blocks programs installed via the Windows Installer.  I am unaware of a way to block software installation outside of locking down the Windows Installer.

Comment: Does this prevent installation of  programs that don't use Windows installer?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Nothing can do that, unless you block all applications, except those on a whitelist

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, and by not mentioning that, this answer creates the impression all installations are blocked.

Comment: I agree with Ramhound, I am unaware of any native configuration that will prevent it.  Other than locking down common installation folders and blocking specific file types.  But that could introduce other issues and be difficult to manage.

Comment: Of course all three of us failed to notice this is a spam question.  The example application only exists on iOS

Comment: @Ramhound Steam or Roblox. Which one?

Comment: @Ramhound What? "You can access Roblox on PC, Mac, iOS, Android, Amazon Devices, and Xbox One. Roblox adventures are accessible from any device, so players can imagine with their friends regardless of where they are."

Comment: @DavidPostill Must be the mobile website that’s preventing me from seeing that.

Comment: The `Disable Windows Installer` option isn't available in my case. Windows 10 here

Comment: @asprin What about `Turn off Windows Installer`? That's what I have.