# Windows 10: Disabling in-app app installation

Tags: windows-10, administration, advertisements, non-admin

I have setup a non-admin account for my kids in Windows 10 and installed a game from Microsoft Store (To make it specific: Dragon Mania Legends, it is an online game and needs network connection). The problem is that this game advertises other developer's games and when kids click on ads, they'll be installed in background, without asking anything and without pausing or exiting the game. Kind of an *in-app app installation*.
Except uninstalling the game, is there anyway to prevent this?

I read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1288007/prevent-non-admin-user-from-installing-programs) it was not helpful. Neither [this one](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-installing-unwanted-apps/b0209eb9-3594-43ed-9b09-3ec115dd613d?auth=1).

Comment: If the game doesn't require network, try to block it in Windows Firewall. No network, no ads, no background install.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I am sorry. I forgot to mention that it is an online game. I'll edit my question.